# Prevent Right Floated Elements from Swapping

Tags: html, css, css-float

It seems like every time I float two elements to the right, they get swapped. This doesn't  occur for left floated elements, and it seems to be in every browser.

Here's an example:

CODE:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .right {
        float: right;
    }
</style>
<div class="right">DIV ONE</div>
<div class="right">DIV TWO</div>
```

RENDERED:

```
DIV TWO DIV ONE
```

It's not really a major issue but it does cause confusion when swapping code with coworkers. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: there is no solution for this other than swaping them.

Comment: It's not swapping. It's completely right. Imagine, your DIV ONE goes to the first place in the right, and your DIV TWO goes to the following right :D

Comment: Right, but in relation to the HTML it seems swapped. I get that that's what the CSS is supposed to do, but it's a bit confusing for anyone just looking at the HTML.

Comment: Swap your div's like <div class="right">DIV TWO</div><div class="right">DIV ONE</div>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another possible option is to, instead of FLOATING right, just `text-align: right;`. Then, mark each DIV as `display: inline-block;` instead of `block`. Depending on your exact situation, this might cause problems, but in a lot of other cases, it'll work just fine.

If problems arise, you can stick the two DIVs in a wrapper, and float that to the right, and then use my solution. However, that's a little less semantic, but I suppose it ultimately doesn't matter that much. It's up to you!

Comment: Ooh. This answers the actual question at the core of the question :D +1

Answer (score 1):

Like left-floated elements, which float as far left as possible until they hit another left-floated element, right-floated elements will float as far right as possible until they hit another right-floated element. That's actually good, consistent behavior, confusing as it may be at first glance.

If you're feeling really crazy, you might try something like swapping the elements with Javascript after the fact…but that'll wreak havoc for your non-JS users and ultimately confuse the issue even more with developers who know how right-floats are *supposed* to behave. Swapping the HTML order really is the way to go here, sorry :/

Comment: That's what I figured. Going to wait a while to see if anyone else has a fix and if not I'll accept yours.