# When float two elements right they switch positions

Tags: html, css, css-float

I need to position two of my elements on the right hand side of the parent element, however, when using the `float: right` property, it makes the elements to switch positions.

I had a look at this thread: [Prevent Right Floated Elements from Swapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249380/prevent-right-floated-elements-from-swapping) however, adding the `display: inline-block` and `text-align: right` didn't solve the problem.

Here is a

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.element1 {
  float: right;
  height: 20px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
.element2 {
  float: right;
  height: 20px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element1">1</div>
  <div class="element2">2</div>
</div>
```

My desired result would be blue element followed by yellow element.

**UPDATE:**

I do understand that this is expected behaviour and the second element is send all the way to the right after the first element, and I do know that changing the elements around would fix the problem, however, just wondering if there is a CSS solution for it.

Comment: You should use `display: flex`

Comment: The answer to the question you linked to suggest to use `display: inline-block;` and `text-align: right;` on the .container which removes the need for `float: right` on your elements. As @HerrSerker suggested, you might give flexbox a try as well (in which case you will need to use `align-items: flex-end` on the container)

Comment: In my container, I have some other items that float left, will the flex box take this into consideration?

Comment: You should  have mentioned that also in you question. Yes it does: See here https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/dQxMdO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.element4 {
  margin-right: auto;
}
.element5 {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}

.element {
  height: 20px;
  width: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}


.element1 {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
.element2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
}

.element3 {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
.element4 {
  background-color: gold;
  color: black;
}

.element5 {
  background-color: magenta;
  color: black;
}
.element6 {
  background-color: goldenrod;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element element1">1</div>
  <div class="element element2">2</div>
  <div class="element element3">3</div>
  <div class="element element4">4</div>
  <div class="element element5">5</div>
  <div class="element element6">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked like charm, did some research on the flex and it seems to be a powerful property. I will do my homework on this part.

Comment: @BareFeet This might help: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour, either switch your elements around in your HTML or use another method of positioning besides float.

It floats the first element first, then it sees the next one and this then needs to be floated over again so it moves past the original one.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that it is expected behaviour and the second element is sent all the way to the right after the first element. I am just wondering if there is a CSS solution to the problem instead of changing the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

use this.

```css
.container{
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position:relative;
}
.element1 {
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.element2 {
  position:absolute;
  right:10px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element1">
  </div>
  <div class="element2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the result is still the same. Element 2 | Element 1. What I need it Element 1 | Element 2